# Textbox on a webpage which outputs H1 to H6 and repeating

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**I dont want anyone to make my homework, i just want to ask if someone can advise me to the right way, before more people put these kind of comments.**

I have an assignment where i have to make a webpage with a textbox and a button. The user must put text in the textbox and when pressing the button, it should display in H1. When pressing again it should display in H2, this till H6 and then repeating itself to H1.

The previous assignment asked me to make a Textbox and a Button which only displays the users text in normal letters.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
  <title>Paragraaf op tekstvlak.</title>
  <script>
    var index = 1;

    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('btnKnop1').onclick = function() {
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElementid = 'div' + index++;

        var node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
        var newNode = document.createTextNode(node);

        newElement.appendChild(newNode);

        console.log(newElement);
        document.getElementById('div-Result').appendChild(newElement);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Type hier een boodschap die u in de webpagina wilt zetten</p>
  <input type="text" id="txtElement"><br>
  <button id="btnKnop1">klik hier voor Heads.</button><br>
  <div id="div-Result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone could give me advise to solve this puzzle and change this code into what the assignment askes me, i would be thankful. I think i need to use a loop, but im not certain how to. The script cannot contain jQuery.

Comment: Where are the H1, H2, ... H6 that you need to show the results in? People here won't do your homework for you. You should put more of an effort and at least show a code where you're attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: I dont want anyone to do my homework. My problem at this moment is, is that i have no clue where to put the H1, H6 etc. I am asking for advise to SOLVE it. Not for someone to give me the answer. As i mentioned, this is the script from the previous assignment, which this question is a follow up from. I just want someone to advise me where to look and think, so i can solve it myself.

Comment: You have shown you can use 'document.createElement`. As you will see from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) all it needs is a tag name. `<h1>` is a tag, `"h1"` is a tag name.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `div` you can create `h` tag, & update the `index`.So while index is less than 7 you can create the `h+index` tag. ALso there is no need of `window.load` if you put the `script` near the closing end of the `body` tag

```js
var index = 1;


document.getElementById('btnKnop1').onclick = function() {
  if (index < 7) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('h' + index);
    var node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(node);

    newElement.appendChild(newNode);
    document.getElementById('div-Result').appendChild(newElement);
    index++;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Type hier een boodschap die u in de webpagina wilt zetten</p>
<input type="text" id="txtElement"><br>
<button id="btnKnop1">klik hier voor Heads.</button><br>
<div id="div-Result"></div>
```

Comment: When i copy ur example in my script it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at helpertest.html:9   And sorry, i forgot to mention, i have to use window.onload in this whole chapter and make it so i call the .JS file in my html.

Comment: So you have to put this code inside `window.load`, because you are adding script inside the `head` tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div you can use h tag. The corrected code is given below,
Instead of div you can create h tag

```
var index = 1;

document.getElementById('btnKnop1').onclick = function() {
    var newElement = document.createElement('h' + index);
    var node = document.getElementById('txtElement').value;
    var newNode = document.createTextNode(node);

    newElement.appendChild(newNode);
    document.getElementById('div-Result').appendChild(newElement);
    index = ++index % 7;
}

<p> Welcome to web designing.</p>
<input type="text" id="txtElement"><br>
<button id="btnKnop1">Change Heading Style</button><br>
<div id="div-Result"></div>
```